# kubectl top nodes OK with only controlers

Tags: api, kubernetes, tls1.2, kubelet, metrics-server

I try to use metrics-servers with TLS secure mode

Firstable, kubectl top nodes gave me that error "Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request (get nodes.metrics.k8s.io)"

After adding "serverTLSBootstrap: true" in /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml and restarted kubelet of all the nodes (controlers and worker) , it becomes better, good for controlers  but not OK for the worker

k top nodes
NAME               CPU(cores)   CPU%        MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%
k8s-controller-1   267m         13%         1444Mi          77%
k8s-controller-2   191m         9%          1406Mi          74%
k8s-controller-3   183m         9%          1365Mi          72%
k8s-worker-1

k top pods
error: Metrics not available for pod default/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner-6f74c69699-lt72d, age: 1h56m40.601601965s

I also added "enable-aggregator-routing=true"  in /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml of the controlers and restart kube-apiserver pods

Can you help me ? What I am missing ?

Marie

Comment: The problem is solved. I don't understand exactly what happened but one CSR was waiting to be approved $ k get csr
NAME        AGE     SIGNERNAME                      REQUESTOR                  REQUESTEDDURATION   CONDITION
csr-2wht2   14h     kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving   system:node:k8s-worker-1   <none>              Pending
csr-46hgc   11h     kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving   system:node:k8s-worker-1   <none>              Pending
csr-4c49m   21h     kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving   system:node:k8s-worker-1   <none>              Pending